# Encrypt the connection String in ASP.NET Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to encrypt the connection string that is being given in the web.config file using aspnet_regiis. So I have the Connection String as

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ProConnection" connectionString="Data Source=J;User Id=T;Password=C;pooling=true;min pool size=5;Max Pool Size=60" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

So I am trying to open the aspnet_regiis.exe as

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "ProConnection" -app "/NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 but I am not able able to open it. I tried even giving the Run as administrator but still nothig opens. Is it the same way doing it or I am I missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run directly through the location

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pe "ProConnection" -app "/NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

Comment: I tried as you said. It says ProConnection not found. Is the -app holds the name of the WEB API application ? I gave the application name but it says not found

Comment: the argument for -pe is the section name which should be "connectionStrings"

Comment: @ChrisTaylor it should not be the name of the connectionStrings?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor I tried  aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"  It says "configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object"

Comment: I tried giving the command different ways but I get the same error message configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object , `aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" ` or giving the physical path of the website created in IIS as `aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\ABC\TestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" ` I even tried giving the Site ID as `aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\ABC\TestAPI" -site "3" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" `

Comment: @trx if you arent published under "Default Web Site" you need to specify the site name - without site name just fails with "A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object."

Answer (score 2):

thinkin you have this

```
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Open Command Prompt with **Administrator** privileges and look for net framework directory usually

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

After you're in net framework directory and you know your webconfig directory example "c:\DirectoryName\DirectoryProject" directory path, then enter the following to encrypt the ConnectionString:

```
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\DirectoryName\WebConfig"
```

Use Aspnet_regiis.exe tool with the –pef option and specify the application path as shown above.

Note: The parameter "connectionStrings" is case sensitive.

Comment: I tried everything 
    aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "E:/Dropbox/NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
   says error -app parameter must start with forward slash. I tried  aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/E:\Dropbox\NewTestAPI" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider" it gives configruation file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object